# Database File not Creating Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm implementing  a software on Android platform and i'm using SQLLite Database for it. I've put every codes about to connect to database in DBUserAdapter Class and Other loginScreen and registerScreen classes have the codings for login and register methods seperately.

When i clicked the Register button the Log showing the Database File not Available. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.. :)

**This is my DBUserAdapter.java Class**

---

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
* Created by Miuranga Salgado on 9/29/2015.
*/
public class DBUserAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_PASSHINT = "passHint";
public static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "usersdb";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "userInfo";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username varchar(100)TEXT NOT NULL, password varchar(100)TEXT NOT NULL, passHint varchar(100)TEXT NOT NULL);";

private Context context = null;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
public SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBUserAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading Database from Version "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+", Which will Destroy all old Data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userInfo");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public void open() throws SQLException{
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    db.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance(){
    return db;
}

public boolean AddUser(String username, String password, String passHint){
    try {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSHINT, passHint);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean Login(String username, String password) throws SQLException{
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username, password});
    if(cursor != null){
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public String getPassword(String userName){
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, "username=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount()<1){
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}

public boolean register(String username, String password, String passHint)throws SQLException{
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE+" VALUES('?', '?', '?', '?');", new String[]{username, password, passHint});
    if(cursor != null){
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

---

### **This is my loginScreen.java Class**

```
public class loginScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

    final EditText loginUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputUser);
    final EditText loginPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPass);

    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = loginUser.getText().toString();
            String password = loginPass.getText().toString();
            //String relPassword = userAdapter.getPassword(username);
            try {
                if (username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
                    DBUserAdapter dbAdapter = new DBUserAdapter(loginScreen.this);
                    dbAdapter.open();
                    if (dbAdapter.Login(username, password)) {
                        Toast.makeText(loginScreen.this, "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(loginScreen.this, "Invalid Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    dbAdapter.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(loginScreen.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //if(password.equals(relPassword)) {
            //    Toast.makeText(loginScreen.this, "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //}
            //else {
            //    Toast.makeText(loginScreen.this, "Sorry, Invalid Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //}
        }
    });

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(loginScreen.this, registerScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

---

**This is registerScreen.java Class**

---

```
public class registerScreen extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registerscreen);

    final EditText regUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regUserName);
    final EditText regPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regPassword);
    final EditText regPassHint = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regPassHint);

    Button regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAcc);
    regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = regUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = regPassword.getText().toString();
            String passHint = regPassHint.getText().toString();
            try {
                if (username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0 && passHint.length() > 0){
                    DBUserAdapter dbAdapter = new DBUserAdapter(registerScreen.this);
                    dbAdapter.open();
                    if(dbAdapter.AddUser(username, password, passHint)){
                        Toast.makeText(registerScreen.this, "You're Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(registerScreen.this, "User Not Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    dbAdapter.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(registerScreen.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }

    });
}
}
```

---

**This is Error Log**

---

```
      09-30 00:28:57.821       482-482/supprioritizer.warnerit.com.supermarketprioritizer E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: userInfo
09-30 00:28:57.829      482-482/supprioritizer.warnerit.com.supermarketprioritizer E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting passHint=123 password=123 username=Randula
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: userInfo (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO userInfo(passHint,password,username) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:891)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:502)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
            at supprioritizer.warnerit.com.supermarketprioritizer.DBUserAdapter.AddUser(DBUserAdapter.java:73)
            at supprioritizer.warnerit.com.supermarketprioritizer.registerScreen$1.onClick(registerScreen.java:37)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4797)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19899)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5309)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: its clear, `no such table: userInfo`. but you are trying to inserting some values into it.

Comment: why its not creating? i've already given the query to create it isnt it!!

Comment: yeah i want to insert valuesto database from the textfields when user clicking in register button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
Change your create table string, it is invalid, try this:

```
"CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, passHint TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

2.
Upgrade the database, try doing this in your constructor:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: now its sending an exception saying cant downgrade database from version 2 to 1

Comment: Did you put a 1 instead of 2? Put 2 (or any number higher than the current version)

Comment: public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; //this is previous version right??

Comment: I was looking at the wrong class constructor, I edited my post.

Comment: I don't know what your current version is, it's whatever you last set it to. Just put 1000 or something, if you don't know for sure.

Comment: i set 4 in the constructor, it saying "cant downgrade database version from 3 to 1"

Comment: spent whole a day to fix this.. :D thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your query is that you are using some wrong datatype `varchar(100)TEXT` here. You should use either `varchar(100)` or `TEXT`:

```
String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"(_id INTEGER
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT
NULL, passHint TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: this is one i found. I'm not familiar with `android`. may be help full.